# Returning two array from a method

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I want to return two String arrays from a method(which populates those arrays). Both array are of differnt size from each other. How do I go about ??

`String[] namesOfColumnsFound = new String[45];`

`String[] namesOfColumnsNotFound = new String[25];`

Edit : I just need to pass the data.. no behaviour is not needed to be passed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is another way of doing

```
return  (new Object[] { obj1 ,obj2 });

return  Arrays.asList(obj1,obj2);
```

return  (new Object[] { obj1 ,obj2 });

**Size of return**

```
class xx
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{   
...
Object[] receiver = m();
System.out.println(receiver.length);  //  size is 2
}
public static Object[] m()
{
String m ="suresh";
return  (new Object[] { m ,new ArrayList().add("PEPE") });
}
```

Comment: what is the size of the list when you create lists like this ?? is it just 2 ??

Comment: @Marcos - from javadoc `Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array` - yes, it will be just 2

Answer (score 6):

Create an object that contains both arrays rather than some collection composition. Why ?

1. it'll make refactoring a lot easier if you change the return composition. You won't have to change instances of `List<Array<...>>`
2. you can encapsulate behaviour *within* that object. Your clients can ask that return object for the first array, the second array etc. Better still, they can ask the return object *to do things* using those arrays rather than pull them out. That's the essence of OO right there - *telling objects to do things for you, rather than ask them to tell you what they're made of*.

e.g.

```
public class ReturnType {
   private Array<String> first = ...
   private Array<String> second = ...

   public boolean isValid() { ... }
   public void doSomethingCleverWithReturnValues() { ... }
}

public ReturnType giveMeTwoArrays() {
   ...
   return new ReturnType(...)
}
```

It's *really* tempting to do something simple (such as returning a tuple or a collection composition), but the refactoring pain is sizeable compared to doing the above (I speak from experience having just made this mistake again just now! And that was using Scala - the type inference makes life simpler and it's still a pain)

Comment: i don't understand completely, is there some explanation with some working example pls.

Answer (score 3):

Or create a simple wrapper that will contain both arrays.

Example:

```
class ArrayHelper{
    private String[] strArr1;
    private String[] strArr2; 
    ... [constructor that sets both arrays and getters to access them]
};
```

Comment: can you give an example how to do that for my case ?? Thanks

Comment: @Marcos `class ArrayHelper{ private String[] strArr1; private String[] strArr2;  ... [constructor that sets both arrays and getters to access them] };`

Answer (score 2):

You can return list that has two elements. list[0] would be your first string array, list[1] would be the second.

Answer (score 1):

You can return an array of the two arrays (even if they have not the same length). A List of arrays will work as well. The "cleanest" solution is to use some kind of Tuple type (there was www.javatuples.org , but the server seems to be down right now)

**[Edit]**

There are several ways to make an array of arrays, e.g.

```
public int[][] method() {
   int[] array1 = new int[]{1,2,3,4};
   int[] array2 = new int[]{10,20,30};
   int[][] result = new int[]{array1, array2};
   return result;
}
```

Comment: could you give an example of code how to create an array of two arrays ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here are my two cents: I avoid returning language Objects (like String, int, String[], arraylist, map etc) from methods. I believe that what I write should be in business terminology for readability and, more importantly, to relate the code to the problem at hand.

Here is how I would write it (test code):

```
            ColumnAnalyzer ca = new ColumnAnalyzer();

        ca.analyze();

        System.out.println(ca.getNamesOfColumnsFound().length) ;

        System.out.println(ca.getNamesOfColumnsNotFound().length) ;
```

The name `ColumnAnalyzer` and method `analyze()` should of course be changed to reflect the business system terminology.

Answer (score 0):

You can also return an Object which does contain two arrays, maybe even with some logic how to use the arrays.

Very simple example:

```
public class Result {
   public String[] array1;
   public String[] array2;
}

Result result = new Result();
result.array1 = xyz;
...
```

Better would be to put some of the logic concerning array1 and 2 into the Object:

```
public class Result {
   private String[] array1;
   private String[] array2;
   public Result(String[] array1, String[] array2) {
      this.array1 = array1;
      this.array2 = array2;
   }

   // now some business logic like this, or just return the arrays with getters
   public int getArray1Size() {
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While this doesn't exactly solve your problem of using two arrays, here's how I would handle it

```
public Map<String,Boolean> analyzeColumns(SomeStructure struct) {
    Map<String,Boolean> columnName2found = new HashMap<String,Boolean>();
    for(PotentialColumn pc : struct) {
        String name = pc.getName();
        boolean found = pc.isFound();
        columnName2found.put(name,found);
    }
    return columnName2Found;
}


// in action
Map<String,Boolean> columnName2found = anaylzeColumns(struct);

for(Map.Entry<String,Boolean> entry : columnName2found.entrySet()) {
    if(entry.getValue()) handleFound(entry.getKey());
    else handleNotFound(entry.getKey());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a more "generic" wrapper object:

```
public class Tuple<A, B>{
    private A a;
    private B b;

    public Tuple(A a, B b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
    public A getFirst(){return a;}
    public B getSecond(){return b;}
}
```